# Tailwind Transition element not working with Modal Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-in-js

I currently have a modal opening and closing well, though when trying to add Tailwind transitions, the transitions are not working.

**Feed.vue**

```
     <FeedItem @click.native="showDetails(post)"

     <div to="modals" v-if="showModal">
          <Modal
              :post="selectedItem"
              :show="showModal"
              @close-modal="closeModal"
          />
      </div>

<script>

export default {

  data() {
    return {
      selectedItem: null,
      showModal: false,
    }
  },

methods: {
    showDetails(post) {
      this.selectedItem = post;
      this.showModal = true;
    },
}
</script>
```

Then I have a Modal component which is getting inserted. As shown in the example below. Just added the transition for ease of reading.

**Modal.vue**

```
<template>
    <transition
        enter-active-class="transition-opacity ease-linear duration-300"
        enter-class="opacity-0"
        enter-to-class="opacity-100"
        leave-active-class="transition-opacity ease-linear duration-300"
        leave-class="opacity-100"
        leave-to-class="opacity-0"
    >
```

Using Vue 2 with Nuxt. Everything else Tailwind is working great, just can't get these transitions to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: isn't it `enter-from-class="opacity-0"` and `leave-from-class="opacity-100"` ?

Comment: Just tried that, no luck :(